# Index in style property with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app with react native and i try to pass an index to a style property, to have different backgroundColor.

here's my code :

```
getData(data){
    const items = data.map((item, index) =>
        <View key={index} style={[styles.forecastItems, styles.forecastItems0]}>
            <Text>{item.day}</Text>
            <Image source={item.url}/>
            <Text>{item.temp}</Text>
        </View>
    );
    return (items)
}
```

in styles.forecastItem0 i want to have the index instead of 0.
i don't find a solution.
Thanks for your help

Comment: tried styles[`forecastItems${index}`]?

Comment: @FemiOni you are missing back-ticks

Comment: I used it. code formating  in comments is not as robust as in answer on SO. it looks funnier with double ticks `styles[`forecastItems${index}`]`

Comment: @FemiOni got it. read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown) if you want to know how to escape it :)``

Comment: Your question not really clear what u wish, are you refer to list Random color background or list with 2 colors random?

Comment: Can you show where you initialize `styles`? Why does it have a key which ends in a number? I suggest you create `forcastItems` as an array instead. Then indexing the array is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<View key={index} style={[styles.forecastItems, styles[`forecastItems${index}`]]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access properties of style object by using brackets like this

```
<View key={index} 
      style={[styles.forecastItems, styles.["forecastItems" + index] ]}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create `forecastItems` as an array:

```
styles = {
    forcastItems = [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Now you can index the array in a straightforward manner:

```
<View key={index} style={[styles.forecastItems, styles.forecastItems[index]]}>
```

Note that you should always use an array instead of creating variable names (or keys in an object) which differ only with a number suffix.